# Pressing Siri button disables fans

Tags: siri

Whenever I press the Siri button on the Touch Bar, it temporarily disables the fans on my laptop, is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an intended feature of macOS and has been [noted since as early as 2016](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12488429) for Siri and dictation.

Even with third-party utilities like [Temp Monitor](https://www.vimistudios.com/temp-monitor) that control fan speed, Siri and dictation will slow down fan speeds to an acceptable level while in use.